# Libgdx library integrate in native android project

Tags: android, 3d, libgdx

I'm developing an android application which include a small 3D game inside it. Here i'm using Libgdx framework (used gdx-setup.jar) for developing my 3D model . Since it uses native android features I need to use libgdx as a library inside the android application.
        I follow the instructions of libgdx/wiki

So I downloaded libgdx-nightly-latest.zip from : http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/

and place **gdx.jar,gdx-backend-android.jar,gdx-natives.jar,armeabi and armeabi-v7a folders** in the libs folder. Then I added them as libraries.

My Gradle dependencies:

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
compile files('libs/gdx-backend-android.jar')
compile files('libs/gdx.jar')
compile files('libs/x86.jar')
compile files('libs/gdx-natives.jar')
}
```

MainActivity class

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
btnPlay = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

btnPlay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), GameActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
});
}
```

GameActivity class

```
public class GameActivity extends AndroidApplication {

GdxGame gdxGame;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    gdxGame = new GdxGame();
    AndroidApplicationConfiguration config = new      AndroidApplicationConfiguration();
    initializeForView(gdxGame, config);
}
}
```

GdxGame is my ApplicationListener class.
When I run this code the app crashes with this error :

```
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1606)
at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1066)
at  android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2226)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
at   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
Caused by: com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: Couldn't load shared   library 'gdx' for target: Linux, 32-bit
at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.SharedLibraryLoader.load(SharedLibraryLoader.java:124)
at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxNativesLoader.load(GdxNativesLoader.java:33)
at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidApplication.<clinit>(AndroidApplication.java:63)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1606)
at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1066)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2226)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
```

Can anyone help with this issue? Am i missing something?
Thank you.

[project library structure and gradle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CyuwZ.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're adding only .jar file as dependency. There are some .so file for different processor architecture like `arm64-v8a`, `armeabi`, `armeabi-v7a`, `x86`, `x86_64`. You need to add them. Keep all .so file in libs folder.

add `jniLibs.srcDirs = ['libs']` in soureSets

Required library for android

```
armeabi/libgdx.so
armeabi-v7a/libgdx.so
x86/libgdx.so
gdx-backend-android.jar
gdx-backend-android-sources.jar
```

compile like this :

```
  compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-android:$gdxVersion"
  natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi"
  natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi-v7a"
  natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-arm64-v8a"
  natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86"
  natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86_64"
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer.                                                              i added those dependancies now , and update  sourceSet                          sourceSets {
        main {
            jniLibs.srcDirs = ['libs']
        }
    }
but still same error occurs.

Comment: you're only compiling .jar files, in libs folder you need to keep libgdx.so file for different architecture.and provide that this is your jni library

Comment: thank you Abhishek for your help. I add an screenshot of my project's gradle file and library structure to above question. can you please check it. I still in the same situation. app crash with the same error.

Comment: check file extension of your x86.jar,x86_64.jar ...these are .so file,and don't compile these files

Comment: Thank you very much Abhishek. Now my App compile successfully. :)